# Is it possible to get legendary drop while in a different map?

Tags: diablo-iii

Let say in a co-op game, you are in a different map than other players (for example while doing split bounties), is it possible to get a legendary drop in other maps that other players cleared already. I'm talking about chests, white/elite mobs not bosses.

Comment: Yes this is possible, when you are doing splitbounties you should always check all the maps so you don't forget a legendary!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  I've had this happen to me before.  I was doing a split bounty and then teleported in to join a friend to finish up an area and a star was on the ground waiting for me next to an opened chest.

This is one of the things you'll just have to account for when doing split bounties.  You are giving up possible legendary drops for a chance at a faster horadric cache.  In the end I believe the trade is worth it.

Comment: You used to have to do damage to an elite or unique monster in order to get credit for the horadric bonus. They took out all of this out now, and the only thing that matters now is how close you are to the other players on the map to get the +exp/gold bonus.

Answer (score 1):

This did also happen to me, me and my brother were splitting bounties and after we were done I went to all the spots he did pulled up the map and checked for the big star on my map and there it was one did drop while he was in act 4 running while I was in act 2 so it is possible, I always go through and check each area all you have to do is port to each area and hit TAB and pull up the map to see if theres any stars on the map and if so thats your legendary.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that is only possible in chests, already happened to me. I don't see any loot if the monster died before i entered the map, however.